# How to add days to a variable date in twig

Tags: php, symfony, date, twig

A few days ago the need to add variables in twig, to be precise having a date for example: 2016-01-04 I need to add 540 days for this I use the date_modify plugin present in twig.

To perform this operation you must perform the following:

```
 {% In September modify = '540'%}
 {% In September date = "now" | date ( "m / d / Y")%}

 {{Date | date_modify ( "+" ~ ~ modify "day") | date ( "m / d / Y")}}
```

With this the result would be: 08/31/2017

Do you know another way?

Comment: Do it outside the template

Comment: thanks. Is a good idea

Comment: {{ Date|date_modify("+540day")|date('m/d/Y') }}
date_modify accepts strtotime format
http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/date_modify.html

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
{{ yourDate|date_modify("+1 day")|date("m/d/Y") }}
```

this code add 1 day to your date.

see https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/date_modify.html

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
{% set tomorrow = 'now'|date_modify("+1 day") %}
<input id="event_date" name="event_date" class="datepicker" type="date" value="{{ tomorrow|date('Y-m-d') }}" />
```